# Trying to scrape from a file and write the scraped contents to another file?

Tags: python, io

Warning: I'm new to coding and any constructive criticism is welcome

My goal: I'm trying to read and scrape a .txt for anything coming after a few specified characters (in this case it's '[CHAT] [@]'). Then I want to write that selected data to a new file.

This is purely for coding practice

```
with open("/Users/barge/Desktop/Untitled.txt", "r") as logsfile:
    for line in logsfile:
        if "[CHAT] [@]" in line:
            print(line[44], end='')  

with open("newtestfile.txt", "w+") as newfile:
    for eline in newfile:
        newfile.write(line[44])

logsfile.close()
newpyfile.close()
```

My issue: I'm not getting any errors in the terminal but my output file 'newtestfile.txt' is empty each time I run it. Line 7 should be writing all the characters after the 44th index of Untitled.txt right?

Thanks.

Comment: When using the `with` keyword, it's not necessary to call `close()` on the file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) `yields` an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) (read notes) and `line[44]`, isn't *line[44]*  anymore when you try to write it to a file.

Try this instead:

```
with open("/Users/barge/Desktop/Untitled.txt", "r") as logsfile, open("newtestfile.txt", "w+") as newfile:
    for line in logsfile:
        if "[CHAT] [@]" in line:
            print(line[44], end='')  # prints everything to the right of index[44] for each line
            newfile.write(line[44])
```

Notes:

- [Understanding Python's "with" statement](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)
- `with` closes the file automatically
- `open()` doesn't truly yields an `iterator`, but ratter a subclass of `io.TextIOBase` (read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)), calling it an `iterator` is a simplification of the underling process for better understanding.
- I couldn't test the code.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that the data is lost as soon as your upper loop exits. You will want to either have another `with` opening your output file under your first loop, or open the file for writing (using `open()` directly without the `with`) and using that each loop. Don't forget to flush and close your file once you're done.